# Why does array[2, 2] = 'data' remove elements from array[]?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I've been studying arrays in Ruby. Specifically the effects of manipulating arrays with `a[start, count]` and `a[lower_range..upper_range]` in the Ruby Programming 1.9 book.

Specifically, if I have:

```
a = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

and I do the following:

```
a[2, 2] = 'cat'
```

I get the output for a: `a => [1, 3, "cat", 9]`

Instead of what I expected to be `[1, 3, "cat", "cat", 9]`

Edit: Thank you everyone for your input. All of the methods suggested work. I understand now.

I prefer the Array.new method that was suggested, because with an arbitrary range, like a[2, n], I can simply use, `a[2, n] = Array.new(n, "cat")`

Fantastic, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of it as replacing everything left of the equal sign with everything on the right side. You are replacing an array with one single element. If you want to replace it with multiple elements, use `a[2, 2] = Array.new(2, 'cat')`

Comment: Good answer, but I would point out that using the `Array.new` syntax like that will generate an array with every element referring to the same object, so if you modify the element at one index, they all change.

Answer (score 3):

What happens is that the two values from index 2 are replaced by 'cat'. You can see this in:

```
a = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
a[2,2] # => = [5, 7]
a[2,2] = 'cat'
a # => [1, 3, 'cat', 9]
```

So with the `array[start, count]` and `array[range_start .. range_end]` you replace that *part* of the array, not all the indices in that range.

Answer (score 3):

You choose wrong method. `[]` makes element assignment (replaces selected range on another)

What is you actual looking for is `fill`:

```
a = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
#=> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
a.fill('cat', 2, 2)
#=> [1, 3, "cat", "cat", 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

Element Assignment works like a replacement of the defined scope. Take a look at the [Ruby documentation for this useage](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D). This assignment replaces two array entries from position 2 with your RHS expression. The following expression should achieve the result you were expecting:

```
a[2, 2] = ['cat', 'cat']
```

:)